# What happens during a "relocation has invalid symbol index" error?

Tags: c, gcc

Here is a test reproducing the problem:

```
$ echo "void whatever() {}" > prog.c
$ gcc prog.c
```

This produces the following error on GCC 4.8.4:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
    ... etc ...
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that on GCC 6.2.0 the errors related to this question disappear, and it instead produces just:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This has been reported a number of times by a number of users, on Stack Overflow, and elsewhere.

I would like to *understand* this error, not solve it (it is already solved).

This error happens when doing `gcc-4.8 prog.c` without a `main()` function inside `prog.c`.

---

I have done a text search for this error on the binutils-source package. A tedious googling gave me only [one useful link helping me better understanding the concept of relocation handling](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/manINFO/bfdint.html#BFD-relocation-handling).

The number of errors does not seem to depend on the program, which suggests the relocations in consideration do not originate in this file, but as a direct result of the missing `main()` function. I have hypothesized that 3 of these relocations with wrong indexes might be for `main()`, `argc` and `argv`, but many remain, and this is just an unproven hypothesis.

This is quite above my head, and any information that helps me better understand it, or what changed in later versions of GCC, would be warmly welcome.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  The command line "gcc test.c", where `test.c` does not have a `main()` function generates one error that says, "Undefined symbols ... : "_main", referenced from: ..."

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a "simple matter" of `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o` having been compiled with a newer toolchain than the one being used for the link, and therefore containing relocations that the older linker doesn't understand.

Comment: First thing I'd do is `objdump -Drx /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o` . According to this output section `.debug_info` and `.debug_line` suggest relocation issues. Likely those section are listed as RELOC in the headers. If you look for `section .debug_info` you'll probably find 20 relocation entries (just look for lines with `R_`) and `section .debug_lines` probably has just 1. Probably an anomaly in that version of _GCC_ where compiling and linking without `main` messes up the debug relocations (why I don't know).

Answer (score 5):

#### C Program Features (Unix-like)

- every program is compiled separately into elf format
- c program can use external variable/function reference, which is linked later
- `main` is not the start of program as you originally thought, c lib has a starter program (`crt1.o`) which has a `_start` program which will invoke our `main` and do cleaning job after `main`
- concludes above statement, we can know that even a very simple program as OP showed need to be linked

#### ELF Format

ELF has two headers, as following shows:

- section header -- used to link multiple elf to make process image
- program header -- used to load process image

Here we only focus on section header structure:

```
    mapping<var_name, offset, size...>
    // and special cases
    mapping<external_var_name, offset, size...>
```

Every program is compiled separately,  which means address allocation is similar (In the early version of linux, every compiled program start with same virtual address -- `0x08000000`, and many attacks can make use of this, so it changes to adding some random delta to address to alleviate the problem), so there may exists some overlay area. This is why address relocation needed.

#### Relocation

The relocation info (offset, value etc) is stored in `.rel.*` section:

```
    Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x7a4 contains 2 entries:
     Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
    0000000d  00000e02 R_386_PC32        00000000   main
    00000015  00000f02 R_386_PC32        00000000   exit

    Relocation section '.rel.debug_info' at offset 0x7b4 contains 43 entries:
     Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
    00000006  00000601 R_386_32          00000000   .debug_abbrev
    0000000c  00000901 R_386_32          00000000   .debug_str
```

When the linker want to set the address of `main` in the process of relocation, it can't find a symbol in your compiled elf file, so it complains that and stop the linking process.

#### Example

[Here](https://github.com/zzt93/os-lab1/) is the simplified version of os implementations,  [start.c](https://github.com/zzt93/os-lab1/blob/master/user_program/start.c) corresponds to `crt1.o`'s source code:

```
    int entry(char *); // corresponds to main

    void _start(char *args) {
        entry(args);
        exit();
    }
```

#### Ref

- [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Program_header)
- [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)#Unix-like_systems)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of compiling the code directly, go through all the stages of compilation to figure out where the error is arising (as far as I know, such errors occur during linking). Following `gcc` arguments will be helpful:

- `-E` Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link
- `-S` Compile only; do not assemble or link
- `-c` Compile and assemble, but do not link

Now:

```
gcc -E prog.c
gcc -S prog.c
gcc -c prog.c
```

With the program/code you have mentioned, all these steps are working perfect with gcc 4.8.4. But, during linking, when you compile using `gcc prog.c`, the compiler is unable to link with respective library, as it was not mentioned. Also, we have no `main` function in the `prog.c` file. So, we need to indicate `-nostartfiles` switch. Hence, you can compile `prog.c` as:

```
gcc prog.c -lc -nostartfiles
```

This produces the warning:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004002a3

This is because of the sequence. i.e., `init` calls `_start` function and the `_start` function calls `main` function. This warning means that the `_start` function is unable to locate `main` function, where the `init` call is unable to locate `_start`. Please note that this is just a warning. In order to avoid this warning, we need to change the command to compile without warnings as follows.

```
gcc prog.c -lc --entry whatever -nostartfiles
```

With this command, we are instructing the kernel to compile `prog.c` using `gcc` by linking the `libc.so` library with the starting point as the function `whatever`, where this code contains no `main` function.

This is the context with gcc 4.8.4, which I've compiled on.

Coming to the case of gcc 6.2.0, I think all these linking stuff is taken care by the compiler itself. Hence, you can simply mention the compiling command as shown below.

```
gcc -c prog.c -nostartfiles
```

If it produces any other errors or warnings, you can use the switches mentioned above.

Also, note that `crt0` through `crtN` (`N` depends on the ELF file) are executed before the `init` calls `_start`, which gives the metadata about the memory and other machine dependent parameters. The linking errors shown as

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11

do not provide complete information for rectifying the issue, as machines are not as smart as human beings in identifying the point of error.

This produces a complete executable file.  Please do notice that such code (without main function) is used when we are working on libraries/modules within a project.

All the data provided is done with step-by-step analysis. You can recreate all the steps mentioned. Hope this cleared your doubt. Good day!

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit suggestions @cbuchart :)

Comment: Whilst this answer is fairly thorough and interesting in its own right, I don't really see how it answers the question. It's obvious that the errors are coming from the linker, since the errors are inside of `ld`. The stuff you mention with `_start` and `--entry whatever -nostartfiles` seems to work towards solving the error shown, not explaining what `relocation N has invalid symbol index M` actually means. But I'm not offering the bounty because I want to fix the error, but because I want to learn more about this part of the linker itself.

Answer (score 3):

We can break this down into two parts:

## Undefined reference to `main'

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is simply because the C Runtime library (`crt1.o`) is trying to call your (missing) `main()` function. There is a good overview of the various C Runtime files [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) / [here](http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt).

## Relocation X has invalid symbol index Y

***Note***: This has been a bit of mission (learning opportunity) for me - I've taken a few days to research and understand in the limited free time that I have. It's something that I've wondered about for a long time but never looked into... Hopefully my understanding is correct (though clearly not complete - I'll update it if I can).

This is a little more complex, and hidden away.

Just by reading the message, we can gleen that it's related to debug information (the `.debug_info` and `.debug_line` sections of `crt1.o`'s **debug** file is mentioned). Note the `/usr/lib/debug/` path, which just contains debug information, the other `crt1.o` is a "*stripped*" file...

The format string is found in the `binutils` project, specifically `bfd/elfcode.h`. BFD being [Binary File Descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) - the GNU way to handle object files across a number of system architectures.

BFD is an intermediate format used for binary files - GCC will employ BFD before it finally writes an [`a.out`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), [`ELF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), or other binary.

Looking into the manual, we can find some interesting snippets of knowledge:

> [...] with each entry in the hash table the a.out linker keeps the index the symbol has in the final output file (this index number is used so that when doing a relocateable link the symbol index used in the output file can be quickly filled in when copying over a reloc).
>   [<sub>[source]</sub>](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_node/bfd_34.html)

> The standard records contain only an address, a symbol index, and a type field. [<sub>[source]</sub>](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_node/bfd_53.html#SEC168)

This means that these errors are issued due to relocations that are related to specific (missing?) 'symbols'. A 'symbol' in this context is any named 'thing' - e.g: functions and variables.

As these 'invalid symbols' appear to be resolved by simply declaring `main()`, I would guess that some (all?) of these symbol indexes are derived from `main()`, its debug information, and/or relations.

I can't tell you what is supposed to be at the symbol indexes mentioned (2, 11, 12, 13, 21), but it is interesting that my tests yielded the same list of symbol indexes.

Running `ld` with `crt1.o` alone gives us similar output:

```
$ ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
```